# php_xsl azure extension not working

Tags: php, azure, magento2, magento-2.0

Im trying to install magento 2 as a web app on the azure platform

My issue is when i do it complains that it needs the php_xsl extension to complete the installation

I have found a few guides on the net on how to enable this by adding a key and value in the app settings and uploading the .dll to a bin folder on the server.

but no matter what i do with this i cant get this extension working to install magento

I have tried moving this folder to above the root and into other folders, adding a line in the user.ini

The dll is for the correct version of php

Answer (score 0):

Check if your website running on 32 bit or 64 bit and get correct version of dll based on it. Also check /LogFiles/php_errors.log. You will see if your app is throwing any extension related error.

Last you can try adding extension using ini folder.

Comment: After checking the logs i have found the following error

Comment: apologies it cut my comment off the error is as follows cannot find module (path to extension) unknown error on line 0

Comment: No problem. That means it is not finding the extension. Did you try the steps below given by Gary Liu?

Answer (score 0):

I had a testing project on Azure Web Apps, and it seems that Azure Web Apps environment has contains the extension dll file `php_xsl.dll` but don't enable this extension in `php.ini`.

To enable the extension on Azure Web Apps, you can try the following steps:

1. Add an App Setting to your Web App with the key **PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR** and value `d:\home\site\wwwroot\ini`
2. Create an ini file in `d:\home\site\wwwroot\ini` (you can simply create a folder named `ini` in your root directory of you application) called `extensions.ini`
3. Add configuration settings to the `extensions.ini` file using the same syntax you would use in a `php.ini` file. For example:
   `extension = php_xsl.dll`
4. Restart your Web App to load the changes, you can use `phpinfo()` to check the extensions.

Or you can create two source sample files at http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples-collection.php and then use the test code snippet at https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php to test the extension installation.

Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime for more info.